# Create function that returns tuple of two functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Basically, I want to create a function that returns two functions that can be used in the ES6 Promise API. I think it's called a "tuple". Something like this:

```
 //start code

    var provider = function (a) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(a * 5);
        }, 2000);
      });
    };

    function makeProviders(num){

      return [
         function onResolved(){
           return provider(num);
         },
         function onRejected(){
           console.error('Dahm daniel.');
         }
      ]
    }

    provider(5).then.apply(null, makeProviders(3)).then(function(val){
        console.log('val => ', val);
    });

//end code
```

However, I get this weird error:

```
provider(5).then.apply(null, makeProviders(3)).then(function(val){
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null
    at then (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Olegzandr/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/siamese/test/test2.js:32:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:962:3
```

Is this the right way (or only way) to return two functions from one function to be used to immediately invoke another function?

Comment: what's happening is definitely that the promise object (this) in the promise is now bound to null instead of the promise object instance itself. So it looks like this methodology won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're passing the wrong `this` value to `apply`. To work, it would need to be

```
 Promise.prototype.then.apply(provider(5), makeProviders(3))
```

As has been pointed out in the other answers, this can also be solved elegantly with the spread syntax in ES6.
However, depending on your use case a better solution than creating a function that returns a tuple of functions might be a function that transforms one promise into another:

```
function makeProviders(promise, num){
  return promise.then(function onResolved(){
    return provider(num);
  }, function onRejected(){
    console.error('Dahm daniel.');
  });
}
makeProviders(provider(5), 3).…
```

Or more elegantly using the [proposed bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator):

```
function makeProviders(num){
  return this.then(function onResolved(){
    return provider(num);
  }, function onRejected(){
    console.error('Dahm daniel.');
  });
}
provider(5)::makeProviders(3).…
```

Alternatively, if you want to focus on reusability of the result you can use currying:

```
function makeProviders(num){
  function onResolved(){
    return provider(num);
  }
  function onRejected(){
    console.error('Dahm daniel.');
  }
  return promise => promise.then(onResolved, onRejected);
}
var myProviders = makeProviders(3);
myProviders(provider(5)).…
```

Comment: thanks the OP was more of an exercise than actually thinking of a real use case, but yours seems good

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, but I think the only easy way to do this right would be to use the new spread operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

I would have to test it with Babel (I think), but the answer would be:

```
provider(5).then(...makeProviders(3)).then(function(val){
    console.log('val => ', val);
});
```

Comment: you beat me to the answer, gg

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "spread operator"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

```
var provider = function (a) {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(a * 5);
    }, 2000);
  });

};

function makeProviders(num){

  return [
     function onResolved(){
       return provider(num);
     },
     function onRejected(){
       console.error('Dahm daniel.');
     }
  ]


}


provider(5).then(...makeProviders(3)).then(function(val){
    console.log('val => ', val);
});
```

Comment: thanks ;) you have that right, if there are other ways lmk